# Convert Data Rows into string array c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net

I want to convert my data table rows data into string array,
plse guide my.....
i tried this but its showing nullException

[image]

Comment: remove ["Model"] from your code.you need just values and num.ToString() get values

Comment: did you try `num["model"]` instead of `num["Model"]`?

Comment: and you better use for Instead foreach and remove i++ in your code.use List<string> models; and use models.add(num.ToString()) into for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code maybe help you(this is example)

```
List<string> dt = new List<string>() { "2032","626362563","tp 150","tp 175"}; // equil your dt 
List<string> models = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Count(); i++)
      models.Add(dt[i]);

foreach (var model in models)            
      Console.WriteLine(model);
```

Result :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You first need to allocate the string array. In your example, you are trying to assign a value to a null reference.
So your code should look something like:

```
string [] models = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
```

Answer (score 0):

With Linq you could do something like this:

`dt.Rows.Select(x => x["Model"].ToString()).ToList()`

This will loop over the rows and create a new list with the result. This way of iterating and creating a list is much prefered over your example in most situations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over model column and select column values.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.DataSetExtensions;
...

var result = dt.AsEnumerable()     //Convert DataTable rows enumerable
                .Select(x => x.Field<string>("model"));   //Select values of model
                .ToList();   //Convert to List
```

[.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/czPiua)